# Where can I find the expontential backoff algorithm of SYN-ACK retransmission in the kernel source code?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

The code responsible for the timing of SYNACK retransmissions haveing the shape of say
t= 3 6 12 24 48...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux kernel 4.6, look at the [`tcp_retransmit_timer()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c#L356) and [`retransmits_timed_out()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c#L123) functions in [`net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c).